# Java exception in the thread error

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to create a program that will go to specific director(ies) and print files that are located in there.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
 public class FileViewer {
 mport java.io.File;
public class FileViewer {

 public void Srch(String path)
{
File root=new File(path);
File[] list=root.listFiles();

for(File x:list)
{
if(x.isDirectory())
{
Srch(x.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
}
else
{
System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
}}}}


public class Viewer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileViewer Srch2=new FileViewer();
    Srch2.Srch("Home\\Documents");

}
```

}

And I'm getting following error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FileViewer.Srch(FileViewer.java:9)
 at Viewer.main(Viewer.java:7)
```

What seems to be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) may return `null` if it's used on an object is not a directory, or can't be accessed. I'm not sure whether `"Home\\Documents"` exists, but you should probably take a defensive approach in your method:

```
public void Srch(String path) {
   File root=new File(path);
   if (root.exist() && root.isDirectory()) {
      File[] list=root.listFiles();

      for(File x:list) {
         Srch(x.getAbsolutePath());
         System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
      }
   } else {
      System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most occurring because in your `Srch` method you call `listFiles` before checking whether the `root` is actually a directory. As stated in the javadoc of that method

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory

Just make sure you handle that case as well. For example

```
public class FileViewer {
 public void Srch(String path){
   File root=new File(path);
   File[] list=root.listFiles();
   if ( list == null ){
     return;
   }
   for(File x:list){
     if(x.isDirectory()){
       Srch(x.getAbsolutePath());
       System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
     } else {
       System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Note that a `NullPointerException` is one of the easiest exceptions to debug in Java. Just place a breakpoint with your debugger at the line indicated in the stacktrace and check which object is `null`. Then you know why you get the exception and you can start fixing it. Typically this boils down to:

- `null` is a valid situation and you forgot to handle it
- `null` was not a valid situation, and then you need to investigate how that variable could be `null` and fix it upstream

Sidenote for the next time you post a question:

- Provide proper indentation for the code you post. Yours is really hard to read
- Try to avoid copy-paste errors when pasting code. The first two lines are duplicated
- You posted the stacktrace (good), but it would even be better if you indicated to which line the line number appearing in the stacktrace corresponds. Remember, we do not have access to your code so linking a line number from a stacktrace to the code snippet you post is far from trivial

Answer (score 0):

A java.lang.NullPointerException appears, when Java wants to use something that isn't there. Could it be that the path is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
File[] list=root.listFiles();
```

The method listFile may return "null".
Check for the Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

So then you do a foreach on this null variable, you get a NullPointerException if the pathname given to  Srch method does not denote a directory.

```
if(list!=null)
{
  for(File x:list)
  {
    if(x.isDirectory())
    {
      Srch(x.getAbsolutePath());
      System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println(x.getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }
}
```

**May be "Home\Documents" not exists, try with abslotute path.**